# Any way to achieve numpy-like indexing of multi-dimensional arrays in R?

Tags: r

Suppose that we have an array, `x` of dimension at least 2. We have a list of `indices` that we want to both retrieve and assign from `x`. I want to write code that can handle `x` of arbitrary dimensionality.

In numpy, we could do this trivially using `x[indices,:]`, which would work for arbitrarily dimensioned `x`. If we wanted to index on a dimension other than the first, we could use `numpy.transpose` to move it into the first dimension, then transpose it back after we'd done our desired indexing. In R, `aperm` serves an equivalent function.

However, because indexing in R behaves slightly differently, the desired functionality seems much more difficult to accomplish. Consider:

```
x = array(0, c(5,4,3,2))
indices = c(1,2,3)
x[indices,]
```

> Error in x[1, ] : incorrect number of dimensions

Using `asub` from the *abind* package solves half of this problem, allowing retrieval of values:

```
asub(x, indices, 1, drop=FALSE)
```

I am not sure there is an easy way to do assignment, apart from programmatically generating the expression, `x[indices,,,,]`, inserting however many commas required based on the dimensionality of `x`, then calling `eval`.

Is there a better way to achieve the desired result in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for assigning a constant in any 1-k dimensions:

```
x = array(0, c(5,4,3,2))
indices = c(1,2,3)

k <- 1 # Dimension to subassign
x[slice.index(x, k) %in% indices] <- 5
```

However, this becomes a bit inconvenient if you want to do sub-assignment parallel to `indices`, especially in higher dimensions, because we have to match the order of the array. Example for the 2nd dimension:

```
x = array(0, c(5,4,3,2))
k <- 2
x[slice.index(x, k) %in% indices] <- rep(1:3, each = dim(x)[1])
```

The best option I have come up with is the following:

```
subassign_array <- function(x, i, k, value) {
  each <- pmax(prod(dim(x)[seq_len(k - 1)]), 1)
  x[slice.index(x, k) %in% i] <- rep(value, each = each)
  x
}
```

For example replacing the 1st and 2nd element in the 3rd dimension by 1s and 2s:

```
subassign_array(x, 1:2, 3, 1:2)
```

This doesn't cover every possible case for subassignment however.

Comment: I should have clarified that the kind of subassignment I was struggling with: consider ```y = array(1, c(3, 4, 3, 2))```, an array of the correct shape which could be filled with arbitrary values. I want to be able to do ```x[indices,] = y```, essentially. This example is illustrative and helpful for constant assignment, though. I can see how to modify it for array assignment.

Comment: Please feel free to post an answer of your own if you think your modification can be useful to others as well.

Comment: The modification for array assignment is trivial: ```x[slice.index(x,k) %in% indices] <- y```

Answer (score 0):

You could decide to mess around with the R functions. I do not recommend this, though you could write something in the lines of:

```
np_array <- function(x){
  structure(x, class = c("np_array", class(x)))
}

print.np_array <- function(x){
  print(unclass(x))
}
  
"[.np_array" <-function(x,...){
  h <- match.call()
  h_len <- length(h)
  n <- seq_along(dim(x)) + 2
  n_len <- length(n)
  h[[2]]<- substitute(unclass(x))
  if(h_len - 2 < n_len){
    for(i in tail(n, n_len-h_len+2))
      h[i] <- h[i-1]
   }
  h[[1]]<-`[`
  eval(h, parent.frame())
}
```

Now you could do:

```
x <- np_array(array(0, c(5,4,3,2)))
x[1,]

, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0

x[1,2,]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    0    0
[3,]    0    0

x[,2,]
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0
[5,]    0    0    0

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0
[5,]    0    0    0
```

etc